# Multiple echo's using only 1 SELECT *

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have some code on a page to extract info from a database (like a back end system) and I just wondered if there was anyway I could do a shortcut around the code to avoid doing multiple SELECT statements.

e.g

```
<?php 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quackedup WHERE contid='topsummary'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['content']
    ?>
```

but then, further down the page, I will need to do another select for something else, and something else.

```
<?php 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quackedup WHERE contid='firstpic'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['content']
    ?>


<?php 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quackedup WHERE contid='secondpic'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['content']
    ?>
```

is there a way to just do 1 global 'SELECT * FROM quackedup' and then change what I output by using the echo statement.
what I want to do is like the below.

```
echo $row['content'] WHERE contid='secondpic'
```

Thanks very much.

EDIT:
I wish to use it like the below..... possible? At current it doesnt loop through properly and displays 'topsumm' twice.

```
<?php 

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quackedup WHERE contid IN ('topsumm', 'firstpic', 'secondpic,)") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['content'];

    ?>
    </div>
    <div id="photo">
    <img src ="<?php echo $row['content'];?>" /><img src ="<?php echo $row['content']; }?>" />
```

Comment: this looks flawed, why is 'content' an image url? and you output the content first, then use it as image src. also, you are closing the div tag before opening it … looking at the contids it looks like your table is transposed. are you sure, those values should be rows and not columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can select all rows which match your criteria, and then output them in a loop:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quackedup WHERE contid IN ('secondpic', 'topsummary', '…')") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo htmlspecialchars($row['content']);
}
```

Comment: never make your functions output anything, but return only

Comment: @col. shrapnel: i'm sorry, what? there are no functions involved, except the php builtin ones

Comment: thanks for the answer, you see i already tried this, and it didnt work how i wanted it. im not sure if ive misunderstood the code at all. ill edit the main OP to include more code and how i wish to use it :)

Comment: @ben: why did it not work? what output did you expect and what was the actual output?

Comment: would it work in that aspect? using it for image links :). i think i may have found the reason it didnt work :)
sorry- output was that it printed out 'topsumm' twice,

Comment: output was …? i commented on the question, coz i feel that there is something wrong with the way the table is structured

Comment: and if i add in another "<?php echo $row['content']; ?>" it just prints the 'topsumm again, rather than moving to the next 'content'

Comment: content is the page content, like for use on a CMS
content for 'topsum' is writing, but content for 'firstpic' is a img url that the end user may change. 
this all works with separate individual SELECT statements using WHERE but I just wondered if there was a much easier way to do it.

Comment: yes, because `$row` is filled once, when calling `mysql_fetch_*()` and then stays that way. moving to the next row happens when calling `mysql_fetch_*()`. using it for image links would obviously work, but still, the table looks skewed. wouldn't it make sense for you, to have 'firstpic', 'secondpic' as columns? you could then simply do `SELECT firstpic, secondpic FROM quackedup WHERE id=?`

Comment: and then use `$row['firstpic']` `$row['secondpic']` etc. to access the fields

Comment: yes, seems practical :P i just thought would be easier to have it all together :) thanks for all your help thoo.